# Convergence of a product as limit tends to infinity

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have come across a mathematical problem that is to evaluate the expression:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \left\{{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{4}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{3^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{6}{n^2}}}...{\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2n}{n^2}}}\right\}
$$
but has no idea how. This could be written as an integral, but it is a product instead of a sum. Moreover, the series converges to $2^{\frac{2}{n}}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ which is eventually $0$. But how can I solve this mathematically? Just a conceptual answer would help.

Comment: Take the log to convert to a sum. Then have you heard of Riemann sums?

Comment: @StefanLafon Surely, I have. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \left\{{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{4}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{3^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{6}{n^2}}}...{\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2n}{n^2}}}\right\}\\
=\exp\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{4}{n^2}}}{\left(1+\frac{3^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{6}{n^2}}}...{\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2n}{n^2}}}\right\}\right]\\
=\exp\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{{\sum_{r=1}^{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{2r}{n^2}}}\right\}\right]\\
=\exp\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}n\left\{{\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2r}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)}\right\}\right]\\
=\exp\left[\int_0^12x\left(1+x^2\right)dx\right] \quad\left(\because \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}n\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{r}n\right)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right)\\
\stackrel{1+x^2=t}{\longrightarrow}\exp\left[\int_1^2\ln t \, dt\right]\\
=\exp\left[t(\ln t-1)\,\Bigr|^2_1\right]\\
=\exp[2\ln2-1]\\=\frac{4}e}$$